# shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation UIToolbar in landscape mode is one pixel off

Tags: iphone, objective-c, landscape, uitoolbar, autorotate

I do add a Toolbar to my view like this:

```
self.myToolbar = [UIToolbar new];
    self.myToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
    self.myToolbar.tintColor = [UIColor BAR_COLOR];
    self.myToolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height-44, 320, 44);
    self.myToolbar.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
[self.view addSubview:myToolbar];
```

In the interface builder I set fixed to top and left margin for the view.
Also in the simulated metrics I set Status Bar to Black, Top Bar to Navigation Bar and Bottom Bar to None.

This works perfect in portrait mode. And looks like this:

[image]

Now when I rotate to landscapemode the toolbar gets resized and everything BUT it is off the buttom
by one pixel like this:

[image]

What could be the cause off this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code is working :

```
self.myToolbar = [UIToolbar new];
self.myToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
self.myToolbar.tintColor = [UIColor BAR_COLOR];
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]; //get the rect of the screen 
self.myToolbar.frame = CGRectMake(screenRect.origin.x, screenRect.size.height-44, screenRect.size.width, 44);
self.myToolbar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[self.view addSubview:myToolbar];
```

EDIT

It is actually a bug occuring on the iOS5 simulator.

Comment: this does solve the problem BUT brings up another one! Now the Toolbar stays at height 44 which I don't want cause it should resize like the navigation bar.

Comment: Sorry I guessed it was what your were looking for. Actually, I wonder if it doesn't come from the simulator. I tried your code with iOS5 simulator and I noticed your problem. But when I tried with iOS4 or iOS4.3 there was no problem...

Comment: your are totally right this is just a bug in the simulator it works just like I wanted it on the phone. Stupid me not trying it on the phone. Thanks a lot. Please edit your answer for others who have that problem and I will mark it as right answer.